# How do I call a GUI form from another Java class

Tags: java, joptionpane

So I have been figuring out how to make this work but I can't find , so I decided to look for help, the below is how my code look like,What I'm trying to do is display the Main Menu after the user refuse to proceed the tutorial and I tried to

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Login {
   public Login() {
      String userName;
      int    option;

    //This will ask user to input the username
    userName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter your name","Welcome", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    //Display option
    option =JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Welcome " + userName + "\n\nWould you like to have a tutorial about this game?",
            "Welcome", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);


    //Ok to continue to the tutorial
    if(option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
    {
    //Call the tutorial class
    }
```

This is where the code gone wrong and I tried to resolve with different ways

```
    else //If select cancel will proceed to the Main menu
        {
         //This is the part I can't figure it out, it display different errors when I try different ways 
            that I searched from website
         MainMenu MainMenuGUI = new MainMenu();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my Main Menu code

```
     import javax.swing.*;
     import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane;
     import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
     import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
     import java.awt.*;
     import javax.swing.*;

    public class MainMenu {
         private JButton exitButton;
         private JPanel MainMenu;
         private JButton startButton;
         private JButton historyButton;

    public MainMenu() {
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int exitButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;

                exitButton = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to exit?", "Warning", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (exitButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) 
                   {
                    System.exit(0);
                   } 

            }
        });
    }

    //Main Menu GUI setup
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main Menu");
        frame.setContentPane(new MainMenu().MainMenu);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code has a couple of problems.

1. By creating the `JFrame` container in your `main` method, you're preventing the UI from ever showing up when instantiating `MainMenu` - that is, the UI will only show anything when the `main` method is invoked by the JVM. To fix this, I've moved your `JFrame` instantiation/setup into `MainMenu`'s constructor.
2. In the `MainMenu` class, the `mainMenu` `JPanel`  is never instantiated. This means your current code doesn't actually paint anything on the JFrame - you need to instantiate `mainMenu` and add your GUI controls to `mainMenu`.

The code below fixes both problems.

```
public class MainMenu
{
    private JButton exitButton;
    private JPanel mainMenu;
    private JButton startButton;
    private JButton historyButton;

    public MainMenu()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main Menu");
        ///// mainMenu IS ALWAYS NULL WITHOUT THE NEXT LINE!!!!
        this.mainMenu = new JPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(this.mainMenu);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
               int exitButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;

               exitButton = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to exit?", "Warning", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
               if (exitButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
               {
                   System.exit(0);
               }

           }
       });
    }

//Main Menu GUI setup
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new MainMenu();
}
```

Comment: It is not working for me still...I'm so confused on how to call the Main Menu when I click on cancel which I stated on my code...

Comment: @ShangHuang The code you have to instantiate the MainMenu class (`MainMenu MainMenuGUI = new MainMenu();`) will work if you've implemented the changes from my answer and don't have additional problems that haven't been posted.

Comment: @ShangHuang Awesome, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `public static void main(String args[])` method in your MainMenu class. You only use the main method once in a java program. Instead, create a method like `public void initUI()` and place all the code you have inside the `main()` method in it.

And in your `Login` class, right after you call `MainMenu MainMenuGUI = new MainMenu();`

you can call `MainMenuGUI.initUI()`.

One small thing, `MainMenuGUI` should probably be `mainMenuGUI` to properly follow camel case formatting and to avoid confusion later on.